# Filter values in dataframe column based in intervals pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pyspark, count

My data is dataset diamond:

```
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
|carat|    cut|color|clarity|depth|table|price|   x|   y|   z|
+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
| 0.23|  Ideal|    E|    SI2| 61.5| 55.0|  326|3.95|3.98|2.43|
| 0.21|Premium|    E|    SI1| 59.8| 61.0|  326|3.89|3.84|2.31|
| 0.23|   Good|    E|    VS1| 56.9| 65.0|  327|4.05|4.07|2.31|
| 0.29|Premium|    I|    VS2| 62.4| 58.0|  334| 4.2|4.23|2.63|
| 0.31|   Good|    J|    SI2| 63.3| 58.0|  335|4.34|4.35|2.75|
```

I am trying to use a loop to count the number of diamonds in each of the following ranges:
[0,1) [1, 2) [2, 3) [3, 4) [4, 5) [5, 6) without pandas. So using filter() and count() I need to determine desired counts and return message:

```
The number of diamonds with carat size in range [0, 1) is xxxx.
```

My code far now is :

```
for x in diamonds['carat'] :
int1 = filter(lambda x: x>=0 and x<1, x).count()
int2 = filter(lambda x: x>=1 and x<2, x).count()
int3 = filter(lambda x: x>=2 and x<3, x).count()
int4 = filter(lambda x: x>=3 and x<4, x).count()
int5 = filter(lambda x: x>=4 and x<5, x).count()
int6 = filter(lambda x: x>=5 and x<6, x).count()
print('The number of diamonds with carat size in range [0, 1) is' int1)
```

but I get message:

AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'filter'

The result I need is something like:

```
 Intervals Count   
  (0 1)     30
   ......
```

by using only loop filter and count and not importing sql or panda

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you like to create buckets by integer and then count the elements in that bucket. The below would be using `Bucketizer` to create the buckets.

```
import seaborn as sns # <- Optional: I am using it to fetch your data
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Diamonds").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
diamonds = spark.createDataFrame(sns.load_dataset("diamonds"))
bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,  float("Inf") ], inputCol="x", outputCol="buckets")
diamonds_buckets = bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep").transform(diamonds)
diamonds_buckets.groupby(diamonds_buckets.buckets).count().show()
```

the seaborn reference is optional. I am using it to fetch the dataset you were using. This could be omitted as you seem to get the data elsewhere.

This creates the following result for me:

```
+-------+-----+                                                                 
|buckets|count|
+-------+-----+
|    8.0| 1854|
|    0.0|    8|
|    7.0| 5394|
|    4.0|17131|
|    3.0|  447|
|    6.0|15058|
|    5.0|14006|
|    9.0|   42|
+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thx. I edited question to show my needed result

Answer (score 0):

Ok the working code is:

```
diamonds.filter((diamonds['carat'] >0) & (diamonds['carat'] <= 1) ).count()
```